# using j in array indices, what does it mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I found this in the Numpy docs.

```
>>> np.square([-1j, 1])
array([-1.-0.j,  1.+0.j])
```

What does the `j` in the array indices do?

Comment: it sets imaginary part of your entry. See for more information on complex number : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an index, it's a list of numeric values.

```
In [10]: x = [-1j, 1]     
In [11]: x
Out[11]: [(-0-1j), 1]    # list with 2 numbers, one of which is complex
In [12]: np.square(x)
Out[12]: array([-1.+0.j,  1.+0.j])  # array of dtype complex
```

Make an array from the list:

```
In [13]: y = np.array(x)
In [14]: y
Out[14]: array([-0.-1.j,  1.+0.j])
In [15]: np.square(y)
Out[15]: array([-1.+0.j,  1.+0.j])
In [16]: y*y               # same as square
Out[16]: array([-1.+0.j,  1.+0.j])
```

Imaginary `-1j` squared is `-1`.

`np.square` is a function that takes an array, or something that can be made into an array, as argument.  Here it was given a list.

Answer (score 3):

`j` is pythons notation for the imaginary number `i` (which is `sqrt(-1)`)